# How to identify context free language?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

Consider the following context-free grammars$:$

$G_1: S → aS|B, B → b|bB$

$G_2: S → aA|bB, A → aA|B|ε, B → bB|ε$

Which one of the following pairs of languages is generated by $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively?

1. $\{a^mb^n|m > 0$ or $n > 0\}$ and $\{a^mb^n|m > 0$ and $n > 0\}$
2. $\{a^mb^n|m > 0$ and $n > 0\}$ and $\{a^mb^n|m > 0$ or $n ≥ 0\}$
3. $\{a^mb^n|m ≥ 0$ or $n > 0\}$ and $\{a^mb^n|m > 0$ and $n > 0\}$
4. $\{a^mb^n|m ≥ 0$ and $n > 0\}$ and $\{a^mb^n|m > 0$ or $n > 0\}$

---

My attempt :

In $G_1$, there will be atleast $1$ b becase $S→B$ and $B→b$. But no of $A’s$ can be $0$ as well and no of $A$ and $B$ are independent.
In $G_2$, either we can take $S→aA$ or $S→bB.$ So it must have atleast $1$ a or $1$ b.
So, option $(4)$ is true.

> Can you expainl in formal way, please?

Comment: I think you did just explain it in a formal enough way. Notice that you don't even have to consider $G_2$: of the four options 1. through 4., the only one that correctly characterizes $G_1$ is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your grammars are in fact [right regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) and hence they generate regular languages. You could use the following algebraic approach to find the corresponding languages.

The language $S$ generated by $G_1$ satisfies the system of equations $S = aS+B$ and $B = b+bB$ (where $+$ denotes union). By [Arden's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_Rule), the second equation gives $B = bb^* = b^+$. Thus $S = aS + b^+$ and by Arden's rule again, $S = a^*b^+$.

Similarly, the language $T$ generated by $G_2$ satisfies the system of equations
$T = aA + bB$, $A = aA+B+1$ and $B = bB + 1$ (here $1$ denotes the language reduced to the empty word). By Arden's rule, $B = b^*$, whence $A = aA + b^*$ and $A = a^*b^*$ and finally $T = aa^*b^* + bb^* = a^+b^* + b^+$. Thus (4) is the right choice.